# Can I make an httplib POST request that returns a status of 500 from my Twython callback handler?

Tags: twython

In my callback handler from twitter, I cannot seem to make a httplib POST request as it throws an unrelated 401 Token Invalid Expired error.  I'm using Google App Engine and have tried the urlfetch function as well.

```
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(create_url)
conn.request("POST", "", form_data, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
if response.status == 500: 
    # do stuff
```

Matching error log:
    Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid / expired To ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the Requests library for the POST request.  For some unknown reason neither httplib or urlfetch work in the twittercallback endpoint on Google App Engine.